# Creating wrinkles on a shirt

Tags: mesh, modifiers, workflow, proportional-editing

[image]
I created a base shirt using cloth physics , and have been experimenting a few methods to create wrinkle ( edit mode , procedural nod set up , normals texture painting ) but my results are not very great

Do you know a good way to make wrinkles on mesh that are not high poly?

Blend file : https://uploadnow.io/f/X6CmBYv

Comment: What you've tried on the left seems ok, but instead of doing it on a low-poly, maybe you should apply a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object (keep a low-poly version) and sculpt in Sculpt mode? Then you can bake the normals from the high-poly onto the low-poly...

Comment: I always thought doing that would slow down my computer like crazy , but turns out it's not the case , i will look into that , i'm trying to find some cloth brush in default blender but i can't find them , i was so sure i seen multiple types of cloth brush somewhere..

Comment: I may be wrong but I'm not sure that in your case any cloth brush will be better than a classic Draw brush, or Crease brush